# Magento 2.3.3 Fails on magento setup:di:compile with an error mentioning InvoiceFlexFieldProcessorInterface

Tags: error, di, setup-di-compile, vendor, magento2.3.3

I have installed the new Magento 2.3.3 version.

After I have run the command:

> php bin/magento setup:di:compile

I have Faced the following error:

> PHP Fatal error: Interface 'Vertex\Tax\Model\Flexfield\Processor\InvoiceFlexFieldProcessorInterface' not found in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/vertex/module-tax/Model/FlexField/Processor/OrderCurrencyGetterProcessor.php on line 24

Please refer the following screenshot:
[image]

How to solve this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you please check this file available there ?


**vendor/vertex/module-tax/Model/FlexField/Processor/InvoiceFlexFieldProcessorInterface.php**

Comment: Yes, this file is available there

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**Go to Below File**

> /vendor/vertex/module-tax/Model/FlexField/Processor/OrderCurrencyGetterProcessor.php

At the end of the "**use**" clauses in 
**add the following two lines:**

```
use Vertex\Tax\Model\FlexField\Processor\InvoiceFlexFieldProcessorInterface;
use Vertex\Tax\Model\FlexField\Processor\TaxCalculationFlexFieldProcessorInterface;
```

and run again below command

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Comment: This solution is worked for me

Comment: @Rakesh Donga - Thanks Man - it works :)

Comment: @Rakesh Donga - Thanks it works :)

Comment: It's useful info. Thank you.

Answer (score 16):

I run into the same problem. It seems only a speeling problem:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/24930#issuecomment-543949135

So it is better to change only the namespace spelling without adding the two use-lines:

```
namespace Vertex\Tax\Model\FlexField\Processor;
```

**FlexField** instead of Flexfield

It could make a difference for external functions that use this class.

Answer (score 7):

If like me you can't edit the file (because our CD will fail) follow these steps:

1. In the root of your project, create a directory `patches/composer`
2. Create a file called `vendor-vertex-compilation-issue.diff`
3. In your `composer.json` add this to the list of "require" `"cweagans/composer-patches": "1.6.7"`
4. Still in your `composer.json` add this to the extras

```
       "patches": {
           "vertex/module-tax":{
               "MAGETWO: vendor vertex compilation issue": "patches/composer/vendor-vertex-compilation-issue.diff"
           }
       }
```

5. Put the following content into the `vendor-vertex-compilation-issue.diff` file that you created earlier

```
diff --git a/Model/FlexField/Processor/OrderCurrencyGetterProcessor.php b/Model/FlexField/Processor/OrderCurrencyGetterProcessor.php
index 6fb4944..86a66f4 100644
--- a/Model/FlexField/Processor/OrderCurrencyGetterProcessor.php
+++ b/Model/FlexField/Processor/OrderCurrencyGetterProcessor.php
@@ -4,7 +4,7 @@
  * @author     Mediotype                     https://www.mediotype.com/
  */

-namespace Vertex\Tax\Model\Flexfield\Processor;
+namespace Vertex\Tax\Model\FlexField\Processor;

 use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
 use Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface;
```

6. run `composer install`

This should install the vertex module and apply the patch to the module and then you can go on with compiling Magento as you normally would

**UPDATE**

As of Magento 2.3.4, the vertex/module-tax has been upgraded to `3.3.0` (from `3.2.0`) and the issue is corrected and the patch no longer needed

Answer (score 2):

Goto file:

> /vendor/vertex/module-tax/Model/FlexField/Processor/OrderCurrencyGetterProcessor.php

Add missing line:

> use
>   Vertex\Tax\Model\FlexField\Processor\TaxCalculationFlexFieldProcessorInterface;

after

> use Vertex\Tax\Model\FlexField\FlexFieldProcessableAttributeFactory;

& Try setup-upgrade & di-compile once again.

For more info you can check module's di.xml file for abstract-interface mapping.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't using the Vertex Tax module in your installation, you can use the `replace` key in the composer JSON so the module files don't even get pulled into your installation.

```
// composer.json
{
  "name": "magento2/testing",
  "type": "project",
  "require": {
    "magento/product-community-edition": "2.3.3",
    ...
  },
  ...
  "replace": {
    ...
    "vertex/module-tax": "*", // add other modules to exclude here
    ...
  }
}
```

This is only a solution if you know your users won't want to use the vertex tax module, instead of patching it.